# Use nginx routing for both back-end and front-end

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx, port80

I have developed application which has Angular front-end and Springboot back-end as component. I installed Nginx and copied /dist folder content to `/var/www/html`. It is working nicely and front-end serving in port 80. Now I need to serve the back-end in port 80 as well which currently running in 8080 with "api" part in its URL. Which will allow my back-end to call api endpoints without using separate port. Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file. I added following part in that file. But its not working.

```
   server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`

```
server {
    listen 9090;
        server_name 192.168.10.10;
        index index.html;

        location /api/v1/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; #api ip and port
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location /{
                root /user/dist; # path of angular application upto dist
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       }
}
```

`

and hit url http://192.168.10.10:9090